# Syntax help. Template operator() in template function object

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, functor

What is the proper syntax I need to run what I'm trying to run in main() below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <int... Is>
void foo() {
    std::vector<int> v{Is...};
    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
}

template <int... Is>
struct Foo {
    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    void operator()() const {
        std::cout << sizeof(T) << ' ' << sizeof...(Ts) << '\n';
        foo<Is...>();
    }
};

int main() {
//  Foo<0,1,2>()<bool, char, long>();
    Foo<0,1,2> f;
    f<bool, char, long>();  // Won't compile
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can manually specify template arguments for operator overloads. However, you can write

```
f.operator()<bool, char, long>();
```

Comment: Ok.  Then `Foo<0,1,2>().operator()<bool, char, long>();` works too then, as strange as it looks.

Comment: To be honest, using operator() with only template arguments is kind of a weird case

Comment: Yeah, operator() was not really intended to take manually-specified template arguments.